# Which Django generated files can be safely deleted

Tags: django

Simple question but I can't find exact answers on the web about it but by cleaning my Django app before it is ready I was thinking about which Django unused files I could safely delete to clean my app paths.

The one I'm not using and wondering about :

- admin.py
- apps.py
- test.py
- models.py

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Here, every file is relevant, but test is optional, whether you create or not, but creating test is often good, tests are the signs of broader applications, they makes  your code more attractive, they identify problem and also prevent them, see a simple tutorial of [tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial05/) from django-doc.

Comment: If there is nothing inside and apps that have them are not used anymore then they can be removed

Comment: @BartoszStasiak But it should not be removed, also in case of using signals, I think, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files are required to run the program except the test in app directory and the app>migrations> folder files except **init**.py
and for sure db.sqlite3